# c# change button and textbox color with xml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Guys first of all i want to apologize to you about my english. I'm not so good about that. I want to change button and textbox text color and back ground color to using xml.i have xml file like that.It's should work when the program is starting. I hope ı can express myself.

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF−8”?> 
<components> 
 <textbox type=” first ”> 
 <textcolor>BLACK</ textcolor> 
 <bgcolor>WHITE</bgcolor> 
 </textbox> 
 <textbox type=” second ”> 
 <textcolor>RED</ textcolor> 
 <bgcolor>WHITE</bgcolor> 
 </textbox> 
 <button> 
 <textcolor>BLUE</ textcolor> 
 <bgcolor>YELLOW</bgcolor> 
 </button> 
 </components>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LINQ-to-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx) , so that you can do `var doc = XDocument.Load("yourfilepath")`.

For example if your application is in Windows Forms you can use this

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load("settings.xml");
        var textboxes = doc.Descendants("textbox");

        foreach(var textbox in textboxes)
        {
            // here you can set as attribute the id of the textbox, i assumed this is it
            var attribute = textbox.Attribute("type");
            if (attribute == null) throw new Exception("Invalid xml file");

            var id = attribute.Value;
            if (!Controls.ContainsKey(id)) throw new Exception("Invalid xml file");

            var colorNode = textbox.Descendants("textcolor").FirstOrDefault();
            if (colorNode == null) throw new Exception("Invalid xml file");

            var backgroundColorNode = textbox.Descendants("bgcolor").FirstOrDefault();
            if (backgroundColorNode == null) throw new Exception("Invalid xml file");

            Controls[id].ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colorNode.Value);
            Controls[id].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(backgroundColorNode.Value);
        }

        var button = doc.Descendants("button").FirstOrDefault();
        if (button == null) throw new Exception("Invalid xml file");

        var colorButton = button.Descendants("textcolor").FirstOrDefault();
        var backgroundColorButton = button.Descendants("bgcolor").FirstOrDefault();
        //button1 is the id of the button
        Controls["button1"].ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colorButton.Value);
        Controls["button1"].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(backgroundColorButton.Value);
```

You must add other validations like the color names must be valid if not replace them with a default color or throw an Exception. 
Also I recommend to use hex format for colors for reliability